# ExtJS - Grid panel not loaded with nested JSON

Tags: json, extjs, grid, store

Hello my JSON is: (formatted for better reading)

```
{"status":{"status":0,"msg":"Ok","protocolversion":"extjs.json"},
"list":[{"getLogfiles":[
{"key":"0","value":"...lugin\/monitor\/files\/x_worker_error.log"},
{"key":"1","value":"...les\/x-worker01-progress.log.1331769600"},
{"key":"2","value":"...\/application\/x\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/Test.log"},
{"key":"3","value":"...ind\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/logfile_for_navi_test.log"},
{"key":"4","value":"...lugin\/monitor\/files\/logfilefilter_worker_error.log"}]
}]
}
```

This json data is loaded successfully and I can print it on the console.log() but it is not loaded to my store:

```
    ...
   Ext.define( 'Xxx.plugins.monitor.store.GridLogfiles', {
      extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
      mixins: [ 
         'Deft.mixin.Injectable'
      ],

      model: 'Xxx.plugins.monitor.model.GridLogfiles',

      proxy   : {
         type       : 'ajax',
         url        : 'xxx',
         extraParams: {
            user      : 'test',
            pass      : 'test',
            vers      : 'extjs.json',
            module    : 'monitor',
            func      : 'getLogfiles'
         },
         reader     : {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'list[0].getLogfiles',
            // root: 'list',
            successProperty:false
         } 
      }
     , autoLoad: true


   } );
...
```

I have tried both `root: 'list'` and `root: 'list[0].getLogfiles`

In `console.log()` the data is found under `rawData (obj) -> list (array) -> 0 -> getLogfiles (array) -> 0, 1, 2 -> key, value`

What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You defenetly need to set `root: 'list'` because your actual data is in `list`. Is it possible to remove "getLogfiles" part from response json (place its internal array to `list`)?

Comment: Thanks. I will switch to "list" only. "getLogfiles" can be changed but not deleted, it is the headline expected from the API.

Comment: "List" only does not fix it. 1. How can I access "getLogfiles"? 2. How can I check the entry point of the store trying to read the json?

Comment: list.getLogfiles does not work. Maybe I have to change something in my gridPanel / dataIndex? Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
               id: 'mygrid',
               store: this.store,
               columns: [
                  {
                     text: 'Key',
                     width: 40,
                     autoWidth: true,
                     autoHeight: true,
                     dataIndex: 'key'
                  } ...

Comment: just tested with `list[0].getLogfiles` and works fine for me. tested on 4.1

Comment: My version is Ext JS 4. But I have just switched to 4.1. And tried `list[0].getLogfiles`. Still there is nothing in the grid. Vytautas could you please post your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fix it with:

`root: 'list'`

and changing Json to:

```
{"status":{"status":0,"msg":"Ok","protocolversion":"extjs.json"},"list":[{"key":"0","value":"...lugin\/monitor\/files\/logfilefilter_worker_error.log"},{"key":"1","value":"...les\/logfilefilter-worker01-progress.log.1331769600"},{"key":"2","value":"...\/application\/x\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/Test.log"},{"key":"3","value":"...ind\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/logfile_for_navi_test.log"},{"key":"4","value":"...lugin\/monitor\/files\/logfilefilter_worker_error.log"},{"key":"5","value":"...les\/logfilefilter-worker01-progress.log.1331769600"},{"key":"6","value":"...\/application\/x\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/Test.log"},{"key":"7","value":"...lugin\/monitor\/files\/logfilefilter_worker_error.log"},{"key":"8","value":"...les\/logfilefilter-worker01-progress.log.1331769600"},{"key":"9","value":"...\/application\/x\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/Test.log"}]}
```

and using `Ext.create()` instead of DeftJs `inject: {}`

Thanks for the help.